# How to print a Qt dialog or window?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, printing

How do I get Qt to print a complete dialog or window? 
I could dump the window contents with an  external program like `xwd` and print that, but I would prefer to do it all with Qt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While you can use [grabWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qpixmap.html#grabWidget) to get the pixmap representation of the dialog, essentially you will be printing the pixels of the pixmap, i.e. the dialog is rasterized a the screen resolution and then scaled to the printer resolution. This may or may not result in some artifacts.

Another way to do it is by using [QWidget::render()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qwidget.html#render) function that takes a paint device. This way, you can pass your printer as the paint device. The dialog is now "drawn" onto the printer with the the printer's resolution.

Answer (score 8):

Use [QPixmap::grabWidget](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qpixmap.html#grabWidget) (or [QPixmap::grabWindow](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qpixmap.html#grabWindow) for external window). 
Something like this:

```
QPixmap pix = QPixmap::grabWidget(myMainWindowWidget);
```

Dunno if you really mean to print it to a printer, if so:

```
QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
QPainter painter;
painter.begin(&printer);    
painter.drawPixmap (0, 0, &pix);    
painter.end();
```

Comment: pix.grabWidget(myMainWindowWidget) fails for me.
I have to use:
QPixmap pix = QPixmap::grabWidget(myMainWindowWidget);

Comment: QPixmap::grabWidget was good enough for what I needed, but Ariya's solution QWidget::render() is even better